# How does multicast client receive individual copy from sender?

Tags: java, c++, networking, network-programming

This question is more towards on how the multicast works for the client. Assuming, we can use a multicast socket to send stream of data (audio/video or even text based) to a select group of NIC/hosts on the network. However, on my wireshark on windows, i see only a SINGLE stream going out but multiple clients are able to receive individual copies. How does that happen? who is making the copies on the network? I checked multicast is using the IGMP protocol, but couldnt figure out how its making it happen.

On the other hand, a broadcast is not using IGMP, but still making copies.

Any comments will help.

Comment: one message always goes out. Machines that have joined the multicast group will listen for packets on the address/port, whereas machines that have not joined do not pass the packet to the OS.

Comment: @Kevin, so, you mean that OS of the receiver is making copies from the sender stream? Then what component on the OS? Is it the NIC or the router for this subnet, where the machine is?

Answer (score 1):

Ethernet switches and multicast capable routers will make copies of your packets.

Answer (score 0):

It *doesn't* 'receive an individual copy'. It receives the same datagram that everybody this side of the nearest router receives.